# java - How to remove all null elements from a Map?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, retrofit2

The simplest form of question is I have a collection and I want to delete/remove all elements that their `value == null`. I don't want delete in place (I want to get new Map so my original Map is safe).

```
public Map<String, String> ADDITIONAL_QUERY = new HashMap<>();
this.ADDITIONAL_QUERY.put("deviceManufacturer", payload.getManufacturer());
this.ADDITIONAL_QUERY.put("deviceModel", payload.getModel());
this.ADDITIONAL_QUERY.put("source", payload.getSource());
this.ADDITIONAL_QUERY.put("adrIMEI", payload.getIMEI());
this.ADDITIONAL_QUERY.put("adrMEID", payload.getMEID());
this.ADDITIONAL_QUERY.put("adrUDID", payload.getUuid() == null ? null : payload.getUuid().toString());
this.ADDITIONAL_QUERY.put("adrID", payload.getAndroidId());
this.ADDITIONAL_QUERY.put("adrSERIAL", payload.getSerial());
```

I add more elements to ADDITIONAL_QUERY depends of what API I'm calling later.

### More details

I just upgraded my Retrofit lib to version 2.0. I have `@FieldMap Map<String, String> additionalQuery` in majority of my APIs (around 100 APIs). According to their doc regard `FieldMap`,"Named key/value pairs for a form-encoded request. A null value for the map, as a key, or as a value is not allowed.", as mentioned on java doc (It's so funny that their doc on web says you can https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/class-use/FieldMap.html).

[image]

As APIs are getting called a lot, I'm looking for a way with minor overhead and fast of course.

Comment: Iterate over the entry set and add to a new map? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Guava, you can create a filtered view to avoid copying to a new map:

```
Map<String, String> filtered = Maps.filterValues(ADDITIONAL_QUERY, new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String value) {
        return value != null;
    }
});
```

Since you're on Java 8, you can shorten the predicate like this:

```
Map<String, String> filtered = Maps.filterValues(ADDITIONAL_QUERY, Objects::nonNull);
```

Comment: In Java 8, a lambda is also applicable here (`value -> value != null`).

Comment: @bcsb1001 or `Objects::nonNull`. But this is an Android question, so lambdas are out.

Comment: Lambda takes more memory space too that I have to avoid it.

Comment: @Hesam They don't take any more space than an anonymous class. As far as I know, they are equivalent in memory.

Comment: @Hesam I didn't use lambdas because they don't exist in Java 7. And I'm not sure what you mean about them taking memory.

Comment: Thanks guys based on my search Lambda occupies 200 bytes more than anonymous class. I'll put link if I find it (I saw it in another stackoverflow answer). but ya, it's ignorable. I haven't tries Lambda yet too but I'm on Java 8. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: @shmosel lambdas are available for android using either retrolambda or Android N and Jack

Comment: strange being worried about 200 bytes for a lambda, but adding a large library such as Guava.

Comment: @njzk2 ya, you are right. I removed it from my project due to increase of apk size. I don't use this approach because of the number of APIs and need to looping per API. I found this approach is b.s. for my case.

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
map.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Comment: OP specifically said he doesn't want to delete them in place.

Comment: @shmosel then just copy the map first

Comment: @njzk2, why copy the whole map only to remove the null values, especially when OP is trying to avoid overhead?

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
map.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is the following:

```
public <K, V> Map<K,V> removeNulls(Map<K,V> original) {
  return original.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
}
```

If the map is huge, then you might even use `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()`

Comment: You can alternatively use `Objects::nonNull`, `Entry::getKey` and `Entry::getValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
Map newMap = (HashMap) ADDITIONAL_QUERY.clone();;

newMap.values().remove(null);
```

Comment: You're just copying the reference, not the map.

Comment: @shmosel Corrected